# Установил модули через conda а также через pip установленный через conda, но python их не видит. Что делать?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Установил модули bext и colorama через conda а также через pip
установленный через conda, но python не видит их. Pip и конда
говорят что видят их и что модули лежат в
папке: `c:\users\*********\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (0.0.8)`, а colorama
в `c:\users\*********\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from bext) (0.4.6)`.

Python ругается:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/*********/Desktop/the matrix.py", line 4, in
import bext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bext'
```

Что делать?

Я думаю что может сам python их не видит. Подскажите что могло произойти и как это решить. Буду благодарен!

Comment: Я не мастер, но попробуйте все положить в виртуальную среду, например virtualvenv и там уже более детально разобраться что случилось.. Возможно так же что модули неправильно вызываете.